# Method for quadratic formula won't give output and errors

Tags: java, methods, return

When I try to make the method for a quadratic formula it won't give me any output what so ever and I keep getting lost of precision errors. I need any help currently because I can not seem to figure it out. Here is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelperMethod {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Pick an option:");
    System.out.println("Option 1: Quadratic Formula");
    System.out.println("Option 2: Newtons Method");
    System.out.println("Option 3: ISBN checker");
    int option = keyboard.nextInt();

    if(option == 1){
        System.out.print("Please enter an 'a' value:");
        double a = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter a 'b' value:");
        double b = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter 'c' value:");
        double c = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
}
public int quadraticFormula(double a, double b, double c, boolean returnSecond){
    return (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4.0 * a * c))/(2.0 * a);
}
}
```

Output: Not giving me an answer for my question

```
Pick an option:
Option 1: Quadratic Formula
Option 2: Newtons Method
Option 3: ISBN checker
1
Please enter an 'a' value:2
Please enter a 'b' value:3
Please enter 'c' value:
4

Process completed.
```

Comment: public double quadraticFormula(>>>>)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return an "int" when you are doing mathematical operations with doubles.  This is why you are losing precision.

Answer (score 0):

You're method should return a `double`. And make your `int`s decimal numbers like 4.0 instead of 4. This will help with precision.

**Edit: Call method**

Since you're trying to call the method from the `main` you must make it static also

```
public static int quadraticFormula(double a, double b, double c, boolean returnSecond){
    return (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4.0 * a * c))/(2.0 * a);
}
```

Then make sure to call it from the `main` to get an output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Pick an option:");
    System.out.println("Option 1: Quadratic Formula");
    System.out.println("Option 2: Newtons Method");
    System.out.println("Option 3: ISBN checker");
    int option = keyboard.nextInt();

    if(option == 1){
        System.out.print("Please enter an 'a' value:");
        double a = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter a 'b' value:");
        double b = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter 'c' value:");
        double c = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.println(quadraticFormula(a, b, c));
}
```

**Edit: method returns void**

```
public static void quadraticFormula(double a, double b, double c){
    double quad = -b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4.0 * a * c))/(2.0 * a)
    System.out.println(quad);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    quadraticFormula(a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: In general, the `4` --> `4.0` advice is good, but in this specific case it won't do anything. Anywhere there's an `int`, there's a `double` multiplying or dividing it.

Comment: No it's not, in this case.

Comment: Well it fixed the error but its not giving me output (the output is on the post)

Comment: @user2809115 Make sure you call the method: `System.out.println(quadraticFormula(a, b, c));`

Comment: well I want my method to be void how would I do that? Like using the quadratic formula

Comment: I have no Idea what you need the boolean argument for, so I left it out